# My application crashes when i touch UITableView Section header

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I added tap gesture for `UITableView` section header. Once after i tap the section header app get crashed. I facing this issue only in iOS 7, but it's working fine in iOS 6.

Here is the error i got while app crash :

```
Assertion failure in -[UIViewAnimation initWithView:indexPath:endRect:endAlpha:startFraction:endFraction:curve:animateFromCurrentPosition:shouldDeleteAfterAnimation:editing:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.23/UITableViewSupport.m:2661
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you write in Gesture method ?

Comment: You should post the code from your gesture recogniser action method.

Comment: post code what you do.